# Take S-650 CS from QGIS program into AutoCAD Map 3D somehow

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, autocad-map

I am using AutoCAD Map 3D and didn't find the coordinate system I needed (Egypt Gulf of Suez S-650) so I want to get that cs from QGIS into AutoCAD without making a user defined coordinate system.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the EPSG number of your desired coordinate system?

Comment: EPSG number is 3355

Comment: Sorry, Map 3D 2023 doesn't have that coordinate system, so you'll need to create it. No other way.

Comment: If you'd like help creating that coordinate system, please post on the [Map 3D Forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-map-3d-forum/bd-p/85)

Comment: ok thanks for your time and help.